# Update Flextable with Button (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

In my Google App script, I have a flextable with 3 rows, 2 columns and a button (beneath the table).

When I click the button, I want, the first cell in flextable (0, 0) should show "There" in it. The attched code runs without an error but doesnt display the "There" in the table, although it displays Called in Log.

```
Code.gs
var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('4C Report');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myssid");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");

var table = myapp.createFlexTable().setId("mytable");
table.setText(1, 0, sheet.getRange("A1").getValue());
table.setText(2, 0, sheet.getRange("A2").getValue());
table.setText(3, 0, sheet.getRange("A3").getValue());
table.setText(1, 1, sheet.getRange("B1").getValue());
table.setText(2, 1, sheet.getRange("B2").getValue());
table.setText(3, 1, sheet.getRange("B3").getValue());

var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();

var buttonpanel = myapp.createHorizontalPanel();
var handler = myapp.createServerHandler("buttonHandler1");
var C1 = myapp.createButton("C1",handler);

buttonpanel.add(C1)
mypanel.add(table);
myapp.add(mypanel).add(buttonpanel);
return myapp;

scripthandler.gs
function buttonHandler1(e) {
var myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var table = myapp.getElementById("mytable")
table.setText(0 , 0 ,"There");

 Logger.log("Called")
  }
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put after Logger.log("Called") the bellow return

```
return myapp;
```

the code will look like this

scripthandler.gs

```
function buttonHandler1(e) {
 var myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var table = myapp.getElementById("mytable")
 table.setText(0 , 0 ,"There");

 Logger.log("Called")
 return myapp;
}
```